# Palindrome Number

Tags: java

I have to determine whether an integer is a palindrome in JAVA. I need help understanding why the code I have written is returning `Time Limit Exceeded`?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        int reverse = 0;
        int remainder = 0;
        int originalX = x;
        boolean isPalindrome = false;


        while(x >=1)
        {
            remainder = x % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            remainder = x / 10;
        }

        if (reverse == originalX){
            isPalindrome = true;
        }

        return isPalindrome;

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not changing the value of x so the criteria `x >=1` will always be true, meaning that the loop will run until the end of time (or someone turns off the computer).

Comment: Problem is here "remainder = x / 10;" it should be " x = x/10;"

Comment: @ManojBanik Yes!! I should've used X not remainder! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little modified and tested code is here,

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x)
   {

      int reverse = 0;
      int remainder = 0;
      int originalX = x;

      while (x > 0)
      {
         remainder = x % 10;
         reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
         x = x / 10;
      }

      return (reverse == originalX);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, and perhaps easier way to check if an integer is a Palindrome could be to first convert the integer to a string, make a 'reverse' copy of the string and then test if it is equal with the original

Something like (completely untested, not even compiled...)

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String revStr = "";
        String orgStr = ""+x; 
        for (int i = orgStr.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
           revStr = revStr + orgStr.charAt(i);

       return revStr.equals(orgStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using x = x / 10 instead of remainder = x / 10 so that x is modified. The value of x is not modified in your code